# How do I invert this 3×3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been following Khan Academy to try and teach myself how to invert matrices, howevever I tried to invert a 3×3 matrix and I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Picture of my answer:
[image]

I tried to invert $A$ but my answer is wrong. I would appreciate any help given.

Link of KhanAcademy tutorial I was following: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-matrices/alg-determinants-and-inverses-of-large-matrices/v/inverting-3x3-part-1-calculating-matrix-of-minors-and-cofactor-matrix

Comment: Your original matrix has "2" but you use "-2" in calculating the determinant!  Your original matrix has "1" but you use "10" in calculating the determinant!  The determinant  of the matrix you show is 10, not -100.

Comment: Your mistake: You need to calculate the determinant of $A$ which is $10$.

Comment: You need the determinant of the original matrix, not of the cofactor matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A$ is diagonal. Convince yourself that *merely taking reciprocals of the diagonal entries* yields the inverse:
$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac12&0&0\\
0&\frac15&0\\
0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So all I actually had to do was get the reciporcals of those numbers? Was all the work i did irrelevant or did I just go wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: @AlanPiggott Well if the matrix was not diagonal you would have to go through the process you have showed. As pointed out in the comments, you made your error in the determinant; it is 10 and not 100, and can be calculated with Sarrus's rule. As well as that, the middle entry in the cofactor should have been 2 and not -2, as pointed out in the comments. Those aside, your working is correct.

Comment: Ok I understand that thanks. I am still confused however on why the determinant is 10 and not 100. At the top right of my page that I have labeled ' matrix of numbers', I got 2x5 in the bottom right. Then I multplied 5x2x10. Where did I go wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: @AlanPiggott It's not the determinant of $C$ you should take, it's the determinant of the original $A$.

Comment: Ah yes I understand now. So if it was  not a diagonal matrix and I fixed the mistakes you have mentioned, everything I have done would be ok?

Comment: @AlanPiggott Yes. I also need to mention that **diagonal matrices are just lovely to work with**.

Answer (score 0):

Just another note, it seems like you multiplied the central element of your matrix by $-1$ in the second line, which you're not meant to do - the diagonal elements are multiplied by $+1$ according to the Khan Academy tutorial.